# Using applets from another distribution

Tags: javascript

There are several very useful applets from Mint Cinnamon which I would like to be able to use: http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets.

I know how to write a shell script to start a **Java** program, for example:
 java -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Dorg.XXXXX.scriptRun=true -cp XXXXX.jar:lib org.XXXXX.XXXXX
but I think these applets are written in **Javascript**, is it possible to write a similar command for this type of program?

When I have created the shell script, I could create a .desktop file to run it, would it then be possible to put it on the Launcher?